# Shutting Down Windows Network Using Bash

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, command, shutdown

Here's my current code, which works but is slow

```
for i in {1..255..1}; do
  for j in {1..255..1}; do
    ip="10.8.$i.$j"
    sudo net rpc shutdown -I $ip -U Username%Password -t 1 -f
    echo $ip
  done
done
```

I would like to be able to go through these IPs and attempt to shut them down.  But if there is not a PC at that IP it has to wait for it to timeout before attempting the next one.  So how can I find and shutdown all windows PCs on a network? (they all have the same credentials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial solution is to just run a pile of them in parallel:

```
for i in {1..255..1}; do
  for j in {1..255..1}; do
    ip="10.8.$i.$j"
    sudo net rpc shutdown -I $ip -U Username%Password -t 1 -f &
    echo $ip
  done
  wait
done
```

This runs 255 at a time and waits for them all to finish. Smarter and more flexible parallelization can be had through `xargs`, `sem` or `parallel` if Windows supports that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well.  I just moved wait below the last done so they would all run at once.  Although I am open to a better solution this should work when I test it.